# PHP Converting 6 Figure grid Reference to Lat/Long

Tags: php, latitude-longitude

I'm using the [PHPcoord package](http://www.jstott.me.uk/phpcoord/test-2.3.php) to try and convert a UK 6 figure Grid reference to Lat & Long.

According to the examples given in the link above. This is a two part process.

**Part 1) Converting the 6 Figure Grid Reference into an OSGB grid reference.**

ie: Convert TG514131 into (651400, 313100).

The example given is:

```
$os6 = "TG514131";
echo "Six figure string: " . $os6 . "<br />";
$os6x = getOSRefFromSixFigureReference($os6);
echo "Converted to OS Grid Ref: " . $os6x->toString() . " - " . $os6x->toSixFigureString();
Six figure string: TG514131
Converted to OS Grid Ref: (651400, 313100) - TG514131
```

**Part 2) converts the OSGB reference into Lat & Long by:**

```
$os1 = new OSRef(651409.903, 313177.270);
echo "OS Grid Reference: " . $os1->toString() . " - " . $os1->toSixFigureString() . "<br />";
$ll1 = $os1->toLatLng();
echo "Converted to Lat/Long: " . $ll1->toString();
```

the problem I am having is that I can't get the output of stage 1:

```
$os6x->toString()
```

into the input of stage 2:

```
$os1 = new OSRef(651409.903, 313177.270);
```

I've tried converting $os6x->toString() into a variable and then using:

```
$myvariable = $os6x->toString();

$os1 = new OSRef($myvariable);
```

or

```
$os1 = new OSRef$myvariable;
```

or

```
$os1 = new OSRef . $myvariable;
```

and unsurprisingly, none work.

As you can tell I'm not very good at this and am struggling to find any help on Google.

My next step would be to pattern match $myvariable and then split it into two variables and plug them in like this:

```
$os1 = new OSRef($number1, $number2);
```

But I'm sure this is not the correct way to achieve this and I'm missing something very simple.

Thanks for your help.

**EDIT**

I posted the same question on [Experts-Exchange](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/29083454/PHP-How-do-I-pass-the-output-of-variable-string-into-variable-new.html) and got an answer. Here it is for anyone who has a similar question:

"Your call to the getOSRefFromSixFigureReference() returns an instance of the OSRef class. This class has 2 properties - easting and northing, so to get at those 2 values you would access the properties:

```
$os6x->easting;
$os6x->northing;
```

In your question, you look like you're trying to access those 2 properties so you can create a new OSRef object. That's not needed because $os6x is already an instance of the OSRef class, so you can already call the various methods on it:

```
echo $os6x->toLatLng();
```

Comment: This was answered for me on Experts-Exchange. I've added the answer into my original question in case anyone else has this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I posted the same question on [Experts-Exchange](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/29083454/PHP-How-do-I-pass-the-output-of-variable-string-into-variable-new.html) and got an answer there. Here it is for anyone who has a similar question:

"Your call to the getOSRefFromSixFigureReference() returns an instance of the OSRef class. This class has 2 properties - easting and northing, so to get at those 2 values you would access the properties:

```
$os6x->easting;
$os6x->northing;
```

In your question, you look like you're trying to access those 2 properties so you can create a new OSRef object. That's not needed because $os6x is already an instance of the OSRef class, so you can already call the various methods on it:

```
echo $os6x->toLatLng();
```